# How to remove decimal and zero from columns of a dataframe in pandas and covert it in string

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, boto3

I have many csv files in S3 and i want to read only some columns from each files through pandas. But in the output csv files for numerical column I am getting an extra decimal values as well.

For example, 97 converted into 97.0 but i want to read as 97 only that too as a text I tried from pd.read_fwf or dtype=object  but still issue is not resolved.

```py
reader = pd.read_csv(
    io.BytesIO(body),
    delimiter=",",
    quotechar='"',
    encoding="utf8",
    quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL,
    skipinitialspace=True,
    usecols=cols,
)
reader.reset_index()

csv_buffer = BytesIO()

reader.to_csv(csv_buffer, index=False)
```

I also tried:

```py
reader = pd.read_csv(
    io.BytesIO(body),
    delimiter=",",
    quotechar='"',
    encoding="utf8",
    quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL,
    skipinitialspace=True,
    usecols=cols,
    dtype=object,
)
```

or:

```
reader = pd.read_csv(
    io.BytesIO(body),
    delimiter=",",
    quotechar='"',
    encoding="utf8",
    quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL,
    skipinitialspace=True,
    usecols=cols,
)
reader["columnA"] = reader["columnA"].astype(str).replace("\.0", "", regex=True)
```

Still issue is not resolved. Can someone help me out, please?

Comment: try this -> reader.columnA = pd.to_numeric(reader.columnA, errors='coerce').astype('Int64')

Comment: can you share sample of your data?